# In $P_2 = {ax^2 + bx + c: a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}}$, why do coefficients in $ax^2$ form reduce with coefficients in $bx$ or $c$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In $P_2 = {ax^2 + bx + c: a,b,c \in\mathbb{R}}$, why do coefficients in $ax^2$ form reduce with coefficients in $bx$ or $c$?

For example, lets look at the set {$x^2 + x - 1, 2x + 1, 2x - 1$}

If we wanted to check to see if its independent, we would rewrite this as

$C_1* (x^2 + x -1) + C_2 * (2x +1) + C_3 * (2x-1) = \vec{0} $

In matrix form this would be,

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 2 & 2 \\
    -1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

When we apply Gaussian Elimination, in my head, when eliminating the $1$ found in the 1st column 2nd row and $-1$ in the 1st column 3rd row, it seems like I am subtracting x with $x^2$ and -1 with $x^2$ respectively. I understand that the first column all belongs to $C_1$.

I understand that we are subtracting $C_1$ from $C_1$ but why can we simply ignore the $x^2$ and $x$. I guess my problem with how this is all set up is that I'm relating it back to high school algebra where you had equations like.

$x + y = 5$

$x -y = 10$

And you solved for $x$. Why can we ignore the $x$ or $x^2$?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not actually the $x^2$, the $x$ etc that you are subtracting but the coefficients.  For example, the first two rows represent the equations
$$C_1=0\quad\hbox{and}\quad C_1+2C_2+2C_3=0\ .$$
When you subtract to get the new row
$$\pmatrix{0&2&2\cr}$$
what you are actually doing is subtracting the two equations:
$$(C_1+2C_2+2C_3)-(C_1)=(2C_2+2C_3)\ .$$
I think you can see from this that you are subtracting $C_1$ from $C_1$, not subtracting $x$ from $x^2$.

Hope this helps!

**Edit** in response to comment.  Note that your polynomial equation can be written
$$C_1x^2+(C_1+2C_2+C_3)x+(-C_1+C_2-C_3)=0\ .$$
Also remember that in this equation "$=0$" means "equals zero **for all values of $x$**".  The only way this can happen is if $C_1=0$ and $C_1+2C_2+C_3=0$ and $-C_1+C_2-C_3=0$.  It's not that we are ignoring the $x$ and $x^2$, we are using them to collect together the coefficients.

Comment: I understand that we are subtracting $C_1$ from $C_1$ but why can we simply ignore the $x^2$ and $x$. I guess my problem with how this is all set up is that I'm relating it back to high school algebra where you had equations like.

$x + y = 5$

$x  - y = 10$ 

And you solved for $x$. Why can we ignore the $x$ or $x^2$?

Comment: See expanded answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! @David